# Application Context in Business Objects

Tags: java, android

So I have a `Configuration` class that looks something like this:

```
public class Configuration {
    private static Configuration global;

    private String authToken;
    //other config fields

    public Configuration(Properties props) {
        //get config options from properties
    }

    public static getConfiguration() {
        if (global == null) {
            Properties props = ....
            global = new Configuration(props);
        }

        return global;
    }

    public String getAuthToken() {
        if (authToken == null) {

            //NEED context here
            FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput("fileName");
            //read in auth token
        }

        return authToken;
    }
}
```

The problem as illustrated in the comment is that I need a `Context` object to read from android's internal storage mechanism. It seems like my only option would be to pass in the `Context` as an argument to getAuthToken:

`public String getAuthToken(Context c)`

but then that means I need to pass a `Context` instance to my business objects as well so they can call this method e.g.

```
public class BusinessObject {

    private Context c;

    public BusinessObject(Context c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        String authToken = Configuration.getConfiguration().getAuthToken(this.c);
    }
}
```

This just seems really messy. Is there a better way to handle this?

EDIT:

As a note for some context (no pun intended), I am basically trying to store the auth token for an API so that I do not need to ask for the user's credentials every time they start the app if the token has not yet expired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `Context` static member that you initialize with a call somewhere in your app start-up code (such as in `onCreate()` of your launch activity). It's not safe to stash an `Activity` context, but it is safe to stash an `Application` context. The initialization might look something like this:

```
public class Configuration {
    private static Context sContext;

    public static void initContext(Context context) {
        if (sContext == null) {
            sContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        }
    }    

    . . .
}
```

Comment: But then I still need to pass that along in my business objects. If that is what needs to happen I can live with it, but it just feels wrong sending Android objects to POJs, ya know?

Comment: Ah that seems like a good way to handle this, thanks! I will probably be accepting once timer runs out.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `Application` that extends `android.app.Application`, make it a singleton, and invoke `Application.getInstance().getApplicationContext()` in `Configuration.getAuthToken()`.

Comment: I have read that this approach can result in a null context being returned sometimes though.